# Perform GraphQL Mutation in chaijs

Tags: node.js, graphql, mocha.js, chai

I testing GraphQL server with chaijs. I want to update user with some data.
In my example, I have a function that returns some user data in object.

```
  updateUser: () => ({
    firstName: 'testFirstName',
    lastName: 'testLastName',
    patronymic: 'testPatronymic',
    phone: '79781234567',
    timezone: 'Europe/Moscow',
    ratingSettings: {performer: true, chiefEngineer: true, engineer: true, customer: true}
  })
```

Then I convert it to string which is valid for GraphQL:

```
getMutationObject: data => Object.keys(data).map(key => `${key}: "${data[key]}"`).join(' ')
const userData = getMutationObject(updateUser());
```

I get something like:

```
firstName: "testFirstName" lastName: "testLastName" patronymic: "testPatronymic" phone: "79781234567" timezone: "Europe/Moscow" ratingSettings: "{"performer":true,"chiefEngineer":true,"engineer":true,"customer":true}"
```

And I perform a test:

```
it('Updates Profile data', async () => {
    const res = await graphqlRequest.post('')
          .set({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.accessToken}`,
          })
          .send({
              query: `mutation update_user {
                update_user(
                  where: { id: {_eq: ${user.id} } },
                    _set: { ${userData} }
                )
                { affected_rows } }`
          });
  });
```

Is there any tool for chaijs which replaces sending `query` as a string. Thanks!
P.S. Sorry if I'm not quite precise. I'm a noob in coding :)

Comment: Hi.  Good question, but what graphql client are you using?  If you are using variables in your graphql, you should be able to pass in a json object directly.

Comment: As I know, I don't use GraphQL client. I just send an HTTP request which is provided by chai.js

Comment: Are you using `chai-http`? What's the issue about sending `query` as a string?

Comment: Yes, chai-http. There is no issue, I just interesting is there any other approach that people use :)